# Masking two images and merge into one image

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library, masking

I am working on a project where I am using different masks on two different pictures and than would like to combine them into one picture.  So far I have the masking (albeit it has some errors on the edges) and now I am trying to combine the images.

1. how can I improve the masking so the result on has no errors on the edges (see images )
2. how do I effectively combine the images into one to result in the third image?  I have been trying to use some transparency effects but it hasn't worked.  What I am trying to do is merge the two images so they form a complete circle.  If any of the original images are needed please let me know

```py
    from PIL import Image
    
  
    # load images
    img_day  = Image.open('Day.jpeg')
    img_night  = Image.open('Night_mirror.jpg')
    night_mask = Image.open('Masks/12.5.jpg')
    day_mask = Image.open('Masks/11.5.jpg')
    
    # convert images
    #img_org  = img_org.convert('RGB') # or 'RGBA'
    night_mask = night_mask.convert('L')    # grayscale
    day_mask = day_mask.convert('L')
    
    # the same size
    img_day  = img_day.resize((750,750))
    img_night  = img_night.resize((750,750))
    night_mask = night_mask.resize((750,750))
    day_mask = day_mask.resize((750,750))
    # add alpha channel    
    
    img_day.putalpha(day_mask)
    img_night.putalpha(night_mask)
    img_night = img_night.rotate(-170)
    
    
    # save as png which keeps alpha channel 
    img_day.save('image_day.png')
    img_night.save('image_night.png')
    img_night.show()
    img_day.show()
```

[image]

Any help is appreciated

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You have 3 links that say "enter image description here". Can you please fill each of those with a description or say what they are above them?

Comment: Also, I'm confused by this because you say you want a perfect circle to be created; then what is the first image?

Answer (score 2):

The main problem are the (JPG) artifacts in your masks (white line at the top, "smoothed" edges). Why not use [`ImageDraw.arc`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageDraw.html#PIL.ImageDraw.ImageDraw.arc) to generate the masks on-the-fly? The final step you need is to use [`Image.composite`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.composite) to merge your two images.

Here's some code (I took your first image as desired output, thus the chosen angles):

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

# Load images
img_day = Image.open('day.jpg')
img_night = Image.open('night.jpg')

# Resize images
target_size = (750, 750)
img_day = img_day.resize(target_size)
img_night = img_night.resize(target_size)

# Generate proper masks
day_mask = Image.new('L', target_size)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(day_mask)
draw.arc([10, 10, 740, 740], 120, 270, 255, 150)
night_mask = Image.new('L', target_size)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(night_mask)
draw.arc([10, 10, 740, 740], 270, 120, 255, 150)

# Put alpha channels
img_day.putalpha(day_mask)
img_night.putalpha(night_mask)

# Compose and save image
img = Image.composite(img_day, img_night, day_mask)
img.save('img.png')
```

That'd be the output:

[image: Output]

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:    Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:      3.8.5
Pillow:      8.0.1
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: thanks I didn't know about the arc attribute.  Can you explain the parameters?  How do I change the length of the arc (semi arc, quarter etc. )

Comment: @sam The already linked [documentation on `ImageDraw.arc`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageDraw.html#PIL.ImageDraw.ImageDraw.arc) answers all your questions.

Answer (score 1):

To you points:

1. You problem with masking simply orginiates from the fact that your masks are not perfect. Open them in paint and you will see that on the top side, there is a white line remaining. Just use the fill in tool to fill that white part with black. Afterwards it should work.
2. I suggest mirroring your image horizontally instead of rotating it. You can use `PIL.ImageOps.mirror` for that. Then you paste one image onto the other image using `img.paste()`. As a second argument, you give the coordinates where the image should be pasted onto the other, and very importantly, as a third argument, you specify a transparency mask. Since your image already has an alpha channel, you can just use the same image as a mask. PIL will automatically use it's alpha channel for masking. Note that I had to adjust the position of pasting by 4 pixels to overlap the images correctly.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageOps

# load images
img_day  = Image.open('day.jpg')
img_night  = Image.open('night.jpg')
night_mask = Image.open('night_mask.jpg')
day_mask = Image.open('day_mask.jpg')

# convert images
#img_org  = img_org.convert('RGB') # or 'RGBA'
night_mask = night_mask.convert('L')    # grayscale
day_mask = day_mask.convert('L')

# the same size
img_day  = img_day.resize((750,750))
img_night  = img_night.resize((750,750))
night_mask = night_mask.resize((750,750))
day_mask = day_mask.resize((750,750))
# add alpha channel    

img_day.putalpha(day_mask)
img_night.putalpha(night_mask)
img_night = ImageOps.mirror(img_night)


img_night.paste(img_day, (-4, 0), img_day)
img_night.save('composite.png')
```

Result:

[image]