# How to join two alpha images horizontally and vertically?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library, masking

I have created  right-angle triangle images using alpha masks. I would like to join them vertically and horizontally.
The masks:[An alpha mask for right angle triangles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAiHb.png)

[Another alpha mask for right angle triangles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyZbV.png)

The sliced images are:
[Right Angle Triangles using the first alpha mask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMRXC.png)

[Right Angle Triangles using the second alpha mask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNXDQ.png)

I would like to merge two right angle triangles in the following ways:

[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6RhF.png)

However,I have been an incorrect output:
[Incorrect output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAnkD.png)

I would like some guidance on how to approach this problem so that I can obtain the desired outputs.

The code for joining the triangles:
I used the following example: [Masking two images and merge into one image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65572419/masking-two-images-and-merge-into-one-image)

```
def mirror_triangles_one():
  x=first_array[0] #The first array contains right angle triangles sliced using alpha mask one
  y=second_array[2] #The second array contains right angle triangles sliced using alpha mask two
  x_im=x
  x_im.paste(y, (-4, 0), y)
  x_im.save('mirror_five.png')
  return x_im
```

Original Image-[Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eg6Nc.png)

Comment: Please post the appropriate two images needed as **separate** images. Mask each with white to fill out a rectangle. Then simply append horizontally using np.hstack.

Comment: What do you mean by masking each with white to fill a rectangle.I split the image into squares and then applied the mask to get right angle triangle images.

Comment: I just mean make sure the other half of the rectangle with the triangle image is white or whatever color you want. I did not show how you went from an input image to the triangle image using your masks.

Comment: I used the put alpha function so when the mask is applied to the image it  shows the triangle.

Comment: I am suggesting cropping the image, create a white image and then do your alpha function so that the other side of the triangle is white. Then simply stack the two images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would do it in Python/OpenCV/Numpy. But I had to crop your images, so the results will not be accurate. Assuming you have filled out the triangle images as rectangles with white, one simply hstack's the two images. Note that they must have the same heights.

Left:

[image]

Right:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read right image
right = cv2.imread('right.png')
rhh, rww = right.shape[:2]

# read left image
left = cv2.imread('left.png')
lhh, lww = left.shape[:2]

# compute min height and crop images to same height
minh = min(rhh,lhh)
right = right[0:minh, 0:rww]
left = left[0:minh, 0:lww]

# stack horizontally
result = np.hstack([left,right])

# save result
cv2.imwrite('left_right_result.jpg', result)

# display result
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result:

[image]